# unable to start receiver: CLASS CAST EXCEPTION while using sms broadcast receiver

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, broadcastreceiver

the really annoying part is that my code was working perfectly fine. And now, out of no where, its giving me this error:

```
    02-28 14:49:43.086: E/AndroidRuntime(449): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 14:49:43.086: E/AndroidRuntime(449): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.warningalert/com.example.warningalert.WarningAlert}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.warningalert.WarningAlert
02-28 14:49:43.086: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
02-28 14:49:43.086: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-28 14:49:43.086: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-28 14:49:43.086: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-28 14:49:43.086: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 14:49:43.086: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-28 14:49:43.086: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-28 14:49:43.086: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 14:49:43.086: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-28 14:49:43.086: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-28 14:49:43.086: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-28 14:49:43.086: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 14:49:43.086: E/AndroidRuntime(449): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.warningalert.WarningAlert
02-28 14:49:43.086: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
02-28 14:49:43.086: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
02-28 14:49:43.086: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  ... 11 more
```

my on receive method is as follows:

```
public class WarningAlert extends Activity {

private SmsReceiver receiver;

public static class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    String body = null;
    String no = "1555215556";
    String number = null;
    int i;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Parse the SMS.
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            // Retrieve the SMS.
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
            {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);

                if(msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress().equals(no))
                {
                    body = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                    number = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";
                Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }

                 if(no.equals(number.toString())){

                 Intent open = new Intent(context, StartAction.class);
                 open.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                 open.putExtra("body", body);
                 open.putExtra("number", number);
                 context.startActivity(open);

                 }
        }
    }

}
```

and my manifest is:-

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.warningalert.WarningAlert$SmsReceiver"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
</intent-filter>
```

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

as this code was working fine initially, i suppose the manifest is fine.

**okay.. i have got the problem! the problem is with the nested class. if i extend BroadcastReceiver in the class WarningAlert directly and have the code inside that, it works. but if i have a nested class SmsReceiver inside WarningAlert class then it wont work! any idea why is this hapenning??**

Comment: What is line WarningAlert.java:55?

Comment: its my class name and inside this, i have my SmsReceiver class

Comment: I am asking what is line 55 of this class? Because there is null pointer exception in that line

Comment: line 55 is this: ` if(no.equals(number.toString())){
                
                  Intent open = new Intent(context, StartAction.class);
                  open.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                  open.putExtra("body", body);
                  open.putExtra("number", number);
                  context.startActivity(open);`

Comment: Ok, I think number is returning null.. Try debugging

Comment: while debugging, its showing receiver is null

Comment: I think the problem is with your context...please check the context and then try again

Comment: @Ajit: i have checked the context. but still not understanding what the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i still dont understand what the problem was. i created a new project all together and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing `number` to null and then going ahead to use it without checking if it still is null or not. The problem is that if none of the messages has an originating address that equals the one you specified then `number` remains untouched. Either initialize `number` as an empty string or check whether it's still null before trying to reference it at line 55

Comment: i guess the problem is with the onReceive method. i tried another simple application using sms broadcast receiver and i got the same error message there- 'unable to start receiver'

Comment: @newtoandroid the error is being caused by the fact that `number` is null when you try to access it, did you change how you initialize it?

Comment: @newtoandroid no it should be `String number = "";`